# Python: bicubic interpolation with GPU

Tags: python, cuda, scipy, interpolation, bicubic

In python, I was using `scipy.ndimage.zoom` to perform bi-cubic interpolation on an image but found that it is too slow on up-sampling. I would like to replace it with some other python libraries with GPU support but unfortunately I cannot find one that is available for python.

NVIDIA provides a nice [example](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#bicubic-b-spline-interoplation) which exactly implements bi-cubic interpolation in C/C++. Are they well-known equivalent [CUDA Python](https://developer.nvidia.com/how-to-cuda-python) examples/libraries that we can directly use and replace `scipy.ndimage.zoom`?

I did some search online but unable to find the bi-cubic interpolation using GPU in python. Therefore I believe there are not many answers available which can cause opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 3):

It's not GPU (instead it tries to exploit threading and the CPU's vector units), but [pyvips](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyvips) is quite a bit quicker than scipy, you could test that.

I made a benchmark:

```
import sys
import time

import scipy.ndimage
import pyvips

scale = 10
n_loops = 10

start = time.time()
test_image = scipy.ndimage.imread(sys.argv[1])
for i in range(0, n_loops):
    result = scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom(test_image, scale)
end = time.time()

print 'scipy took', end - start

start = time.time()
test_image = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(sys.argv[1])
for i in range(0, n_loops):
    result = test_image.resize(scale).write_to_memory()
end = time.time()

print 'pyvips took', end - start

# transform with both libraries to compare results

ndi = scipy.ndimage.imread(sys.argv[1])
result = scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom(ndi, scale)
scipy.misc.imsave('ndi.tif', result)

im = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(sys.argv[1], access='sequential')
result = im.resize(scale)
result.write_to_file('pyvips.tif')
```

Both default to bicubic. pyvips is a lazy library, so you need the extra `write_to_memory()` at the end to generate a memory array.

On this four core / eight thread desktop running Ubuntu 17.10 with the packaged versions of all libraries and a 512x512 mono version of the 'lena' test image, I see:

```
$ python zoom.py ~/pics/lena.png 
scipy took 15.6309859753
pyvips took 1.36838102341
```

A GPU upsizer would obviously be faster again, but maybe pyvips would be fast enough?

If you compare the two output images, you'll see the scipy one is shifted up by a small amount. You can see what's happening more clearly with a very small input image, for example, this 3x3 pixel image:

[image: 3x3 pixel test image]

When zoomed 20x by scipy and pyvips becomes:

[image: 20x upsize with scipy and pyvips]

Which puzzles me. Additionally, they are clearly using different kernels, which is also odd.

Comment: I tried to use `pyvips` and convert `big` above to ndarray like this:  `numpy.ndarray(buffer=big.write_to_memory(), dtype=numpy.uint8, shape=[big.height, big.width, big.bands])`. Then I try to compare the image against `scipy.ndimage.zoom(image, (4, 4, 1.0), order=3)` and found that the pixels are shifted a little bit for some reason. I am not familiar with `pyvips` and please let me know if I used `pyvips` correctly.

Comment: I updated the timings on a desktop machine, and added a comparison of the output. I think pyvips is probably more accurate here. I wonder about the kernel difference, I'll have a look at the source.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. Yes I also see similar shift up effect in my test image. I did have a look on the documentation of `pyvips` and it does not explain how `resize` is implemented. On the other hand, input is pre-filtered with spline_filter before interpolation when using `scipy`. This could be handled differently in `pyvips`

Comment: libvips resize just calls `vips_affine` for upsampling, with the parameters set for centre convention bicubic with edge extension. The bicubic upsizer uses a 4x4 stencil (bicubic downsize is adaptive). I'll have a look at spline_filter, perhaps that's the difference.

Comment: Doesn't GPU only do linear interpolation?

Comment: You can implement bicubic in a shader.